# Can I show the expanded commands that npm runs?

Tags: node.js, build, npm

I'm trying to use `npm` as a build tool, motivated by Keith Cirkel's article [How to Use `npm` as a Build Tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/). It kind of works, but...

```
$ npm run build

> browserify $npm_package_config_src -d -p [minifyify --map myproj-$npm_package_version.map.json --output dist/myproj-$npm_package_version.map.json] > dist/myproj-$npm_package_version.min.js
```

I come from Make world, and I really would value seeing the *actual* command going further, meaning the `$npm_package_config_src` and `$npm_package_version` expanded, like this:

```
$ npm run build

> browserify src/myfile.js -d -p [minifyify --map myproj-0.4.2.map.json --output dist/myproj-0.4.2.map.json] > dist/myproj-0.4.2.min.js
```

Is there a way to make that happen?

Reasoning: it makes debugging the build much clearer when one sees the actual commands. Now I feel I'm left in the dark (though the right thing probably happens). Also, since the `$npm_package_config_blahblah`s are such a "mouthful" (as Keith it kindly puts) it becomes a verbosity problem all by itself.

Comment: Beyond `--loglevel verbose`?

Comment: I think that answers another question. I edit the question to show what I wish to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that npm doesn't really have any intelligence when it comes to npm scripts; it just takes the raw strings and passes them to the operating systems shell (bash for most OSes, cmd for windows). Npm has no idea what variables are, or globbing, or any shell feature.

So you're left relying on bash features, and or windows cmd features. Luckily both have this option:

On bash you can either `set -x` or `set -o verbose` like so:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        " foo": "set -x; echo $bar"
    }
}
```

In windows you'd have the alternative, `@echo on`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        " foo": "@echo on; echo $bar"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how you'd combine these to be compatible with both environments, however.

Comment: Thanks for the good description. I ended up having my build logic in the Makefile, and using npm modules from there. This was only one of the reasons. But avoiding Grunt/Gulp. This was the best optimum for my needs.